# Install Wekan from Snap locally the easy way

Tags: lan, wekan

How do I install and run the [Wekan kanban board](https://github.com/wekan/wekan) on my **local network** on 18.04 ?

*Got a lot of issues and I can't find my way around the documentation. Please help.*

OK, that was for dramatic effect. But I will try to cover the install plus a few pitfalls that seem to be confusing some people.

Answer (score 0):

**What we are going to install exactly**

- We are going to install **Wekan proper**, not any of the versions like
  Wekan-ondra. I haven't tested these yet.
- We are going to install it on the **local network**. I have not yet tried
  to make it accessible from the outside.
- It will run on **port 8**0 and the webserver will be nginx (which is the
  default).
- It will use the **http** protocol.

**What I am not going to cover**

This will be an easy and quick install accessible only from your own LAN / WLAN. I won't cover nginx or Apache2 configs or accessing it from the internet.

**The nitty gritty**

**1. Web server settings**

First, we need to make sure that we are running nginx and not Apache:

```
sudo systemctl list-units | grep 'apache2\|nginx'
```

If Apache happens to be installed you can remove it or for the purpose of testing the installation just disable it. Up you.

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
sudo systemctl disable apache2.service
```

If nginx is installed we need to check that it's working as I have found that sometimes there is a bit of confusion. Check it our with:

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

If the server is running, you are golden. If you see an error message complaining about not being able to start a high performance web server and referring to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf it means that the installation is not complete. The reason is that there are several packages and this is utterly confusing to say the least as when you run `apt-get remove nginx` it will tell you that it's not installed. The reason is that the package installed is *nginx-common*, probably to fulfil some deps. Anyway, get rid of it and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx-common && sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

**2. Install the snap and set the environment**

Now install Wekan from snap (it's also available in the Software app.

```
sudo snap install wekan
```

Now let's set the basic root URL on port 80. For this we don't need to touch any other env variable:

```
sudo snap set wekan root_url="http://192.168.2.12"
sudo systemctl restart snap.wekan.mongodb
sudo systemctl restart snap.wekan,wekan
```

**3. Create a user and start kanbanning**

Now you should be able to open a browser pointing at 192.168.2.12 (or whatever IP / URL you choose).

You should see the login screen. The first step is to create a user by *registering*.

*This first created user will be the Admin user.*

If you get a *general server error* when registering don't panic. You just need to restart the mongodb, the user will be saved and you will be able to use it later without a problem, no need to create a new one:

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.wekan.mongodb
```

and for good measure:

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.wekan.wekan
```

That's it. Enjoy.